# How to generate Makefile from existing xcode project

Tags: xcode, macos, makefile, cross-platform

How to generate Makefile for existing Xcode project ? This is an Xcode 3 OSX application, which has .mm and .cpp files And application links to AppKit, Cocoa, CoreData, foundation framework.

I need this Makefile to support cross-compilation support.

I am aware of xcodebuild, which is not helpful in my case. I came across converters/tools like PBToMake, pbxbuild which are deprecated as of now.

Is there any way?